# Segmentation fault on train_on_batch function, when compiling the model just before

Tags: tensorflow, keras

In order to see what was causing a segmentation fault, my code I have added

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONFAULTHANDLER'] = '1'
import faulthandler
import sys
faulthandler.enable(file=sys.stderr, all_threads=True)
faulthandler.dump_traceback(file=sys.stderr, all_threads=True)
```

Now I have this output:

```
Current thread 0x00007feb62064740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1470 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2937 in _call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2979 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1484 in train_on_batch
  File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/network.py", line 883 in train
  File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/util/tuning.py", line 140 in nn_task
  File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/util/util.py", line 2 in <lambda>


 File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/main/common.py", line 278 in run
  File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/main/sokoban.py", line 42 in sokoban
  File "/workspace/latplan/latplanClonedLossTerm/latplan/main/common.py", line 132 in main
  File "./train_kltune.py", line 14 in <module>
```

Which says that the SegFault comes from *train_on_batch* function.

But, how can I have more details ? I need to now exactly what's going on.

Here is the code (partly, because it's a very complex code):

```
net.compile(optimizer=self.optimizers[0], loss=self.losses[0], metrics=self.metrics, options = run_opts)

net.train_on_batch(train_subdata_batch_cache, train_subdata_to_batch_cache)
```

If I comment out the `net.compile` line, then no more SegFault error, but I need this line actually.. so any idea why compiling the network again would produce a SegFault ?

Thanks

Thanks a lot